# Entity Framework self referencing - Parent-Child

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a self referencing table and i need to bind the date from table to tree view. Parent-Child. My question is How to get tree view from that table using Entity Framework using anonymous type

some like this:

```
var tree = db.Categories.Select(g => new

    {
        id = g.CategoryId,

        text = g.CategoryName,

        children = g.children.Select(w => new
        {

            id = w.CategoryId,
            parent = w.ParentCategoryId,
            text = w.CategoryName,


        }).ToList(),


    }
         ).ToList();
```

Here is the code:

```
 public partial class Category
    {

        public Category()
        {
            this.children = new HashSet<Category>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> children { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You already have some kind of three view, what exactly you would like to achieve?

Comment: @Elias  I edited the code . please take a look again. Thank you so much

Comment: @J. Pichardo.... I edited the code . please take a look again. Thank you so much

Comment: @Tom, Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose to create a type for your purpose rather then using anonymous type and fill model via recursive method.

```
var three = BuildThree(db.Categories);

public IEnumerable<CategoryVm> BuildThree(IEnumerable<Categories> categories, int? parentCategoryId = null)
{
  if (categories == null)
  return null;
  var result = categories.select(c => new CategoryVm()
    { 
         id = c.CategoryId,
         text = c.CategoryName,
         parent = parentCategoryId, 
         children = BuildThree(c.children, c.CategoryId) 
    }
    return result;
 }
```

This solution there is on drawback - each time time when you call navigation property (children) you will make request to database. If you want to make it in one request and you have only one level of nested categories then `.Include(c => c.Children)` enough otherwise you have to make a choice one of the next options:

1. Write a common table expression (CTE) query, put it to view or stored procedure and map it by means of EF. The role of EF is not really big because the most tricky part is the SQL query
2. Especially for this kind of purpose, Microsoft SQL Server has `hierarchyid` but EF does not support it from the box. However there are some workarounds: [Entity Framework HierarchyId Workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363332/entity-framework-hierarchyid-workarounds)
3. You can add something like `rootId` to the `Comment` entity, when each child replay will has a link to root comment. After that you can load all hierarchy to memory in one sql query and map it manually. Given that database is bottleneck it will much faster then make new query for each level of hierarchy.

Comment: Can you please help me in this . Thank you so much
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909078/entity-framework-self-referencing-table-how-to-get-parent-until-reach-to-root?noredirect=1#comment70999718_41909078

Comment: my man! thanks! works really well for my solution!