# Entity Framework self referencing table. How to get parent until reach to root

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a self referencing table and i need to bind the date from table to tree view user control . I use BuildThree() method to get children. My question is  how can i get parent until reach to root parent using my View model

My Entity:

```
 public partial class Category
        {

            public Category()
            {
                this.children = new HashSet<Category>();
            }

            public int CategoryId { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Category> children { get; set; }
            public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
        }
```

my view model:

```
public class TreeViewModel
{
        public TreeViewModel()
        {
            this.children = new HashSet<TreeViewModel>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }

        public string text { get; set; }

        public virtual TreeViewModel MyParent { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> children { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is the method i use to get children

```
   public IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> BuildThree(IEnumerable<Category> categories, int? parentCategoryId = null)
    {
        if (categories == null)
            return null;
        var result = categories.Select(c => new TreeViewModel()
        {     
            id = c.CategoryId,
            text = c.CategoryName,

            children = BuildThree(c.children, c.CategoryId)
        });
        return result;
    }





        Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
        var category = db.Categories.Find(id);

        TreeViewModel vm = new TreeViewModel();
        vm.id = category.CategoryId;
        vm.text = category.CategoryName;

        vm.children = BuildThree(category.children);
```

Comment: Add a property to the Category Class containing parent : Category Parent.  I don't like moving up a tree structure.  Instead I write recursive algorithm that don't need to move up.  I return child info as the return value from the recursive methods.

Comment: @jdweng. Thank you jdweng for your help. Can you please if you are not busy use my code to show me how to implement your idea? i am sorry but i am very new to programming. Thank you so much

Comment: Why do you need parent?  You should save the root as a static property in the TreeViewModel so you don't have to find root by moving up the parents.

Answer (score 0):

If you just looking for a way to populate `MyParent` propperty, than have to make small changes of your `BuildThree` method.

```
public IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> BuildThree(IEnumerable<Category> categories, TreeViewModel parentCategory)
    {
        if (categories == null)
            return null;
        var result = new List<TreeViewModel>();
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
           var treeViewModel = new TreeViewModel();
           treeViewModel.Id = category.CategoryId,
           treeViewModel.Text = category.CategoryName,
           treeViewModel.MyParent = parentCategory; 
           treeViewModel.Children= BuildThree(category.children,treeViewModel);
           result.Add(treeViewModel);   
        }
        return result;
    }
```